# Show that $\|f_h\|_{\infty} \leq h^{-1/p}\|f\|_p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function. For every
>   $h>0$ we define
>   $$f_h (t) = \frac{1}{h} \int_{t-\frac{h}{2}}^{t+\frac{h}{2}}f(x)dx$$
>   If $f\in L^p$, show that
>   $$\|f_h\|_{\infty} \leq h^{-\frac{1}{p}}\|f\|_p$$

I couldn't prove it for $p<1$. For the case $1\leq p$, I used that, if $0<|E|< \infty$, $\displaystyle N_p [f] = \left(\frac{1}{|E|}\int_E  |f|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is monotonically increasing over $p$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you show $N_p$ is increasing in $p$? Does it hold for all $(0,\infty)$? If so I think the question actually just wants you to show the $p\ge 1$ cases.

Comment: let $1 \leq p_1 < p_2 $. 

$||f^{p_1}|| \leq||f^{p_1}||_{p_2/p_1}||Id||_{\frac{p_2}{p_2-p_1}}=||f^{p_1}||_{p_2/p_1}|E|^{\frac{p_2-p_1}{p_2}} $
For the inequality I used Hölder.
If we divide both sides by $|E|^{1/p_1}$, we conclude that $N_{p_1} [f] \leq N_{p_2} [f]$.
I strongly use that $1\leq p_1$